# QTcpSocket and deletion

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qsharedpointer

I'm writing a tcp based server using Qt.

I plan this server to be multithreaded,
so my tcpserver class inherits from `QTcpServer` and overrides `incomingConnection()`. Everything is fine, except when it comes to deleting a user.

The `TcpServer` class manages
a list of `QSharedPointer<Client>`. When I remove the said client from the list, it gets automatically deleted because of the smart pointer.
    My Client class owns a `QSharedPointer<QTcpSocket>` which means that the client's
    `QTcpSocket` gets deleted when the client is deleted.

Problem is, it seems that Qt tries to use this socket after its deletion, causing Segmentation Fault.

Should I manages a list for the sockets only, and call `deleteLater()` on them when I dont need them anymore?
    Or should I switch my socket's pointer in client class to a normal pointer?

```
void SlotSocketError(void)
{
  QTcpSocket sock = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(QObject::sender());
  QSharedPointer<Client> client = GetClientFromSocket(sock);

  _clientList.removeAt(GetClientPositionInList(client));
}

 QList<QSharedPointer<Client> > _clientsList; // From TcpServer header.

 /* Client's class header */
 QSharedPointer<QTcpSocket> _socket;
```

Comment: Can you show some code?  That's worth a lot more then an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use deleteLater on the Object.  Incoming messages may come in after you delete the QTCPSocket.  It is documented in Assistant.  You can find an example here:  qthelp://com.trolltech.qt.472/qdoc/qt4-network.html

M

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess there is nothing I can do about it, can I?

Comment: No, you can't. The problem is that the error handling code in the socket *first* emits the error signal, and *then* continues, accessing itself, i.e. dereferences the "this" pointer. If you delete the socket in the slot, accessing "this" inside the tcpsocket method crashes. That's why one should never delete QObjects in code directly or indirectly triggered by their signals.

Comment: This also seems to imply that using `setParent()` on the `QTcpSocket` leads to a crash due to the deletion that is automatically performed. I had to replace `setParent()` on init by `deleteLater()` in the destructor to avoid the segmentation fault. (on Qt6)

Answer (score 2):

When you create your `QSharedPointer`s you can pass a deleter to them, so that they'll use `deleteLater` instead of `delete` when you remove them from the list.

There is an example that does exactly that in the documentation too:
http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsharedpointer.html#QSharedPointer-3